# handling multiple POST requests

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

with EXPRESS.JS i wrote a service to connect my app to a database, this service is basically an endpoint and inside i have multiple GET or POST requests.

now i have to make two different POST request on the same address.

first POST request:

```
app.post("/accesso", function(req, res) {
  connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    let sql = "DELETE FROM accesso where ?";
    let variabile = { idaccesso: req.body.idaccesso };
    connection.query(sql, variabile, function(error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results).end();
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

second POST request:

```
app.post("/accesso", function(req, res) {
  connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO accesso SET ?";
    let variabile = { utente: req.body.utente };
    connection.query(sql, variabile, function(error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      // RISPOSTA DATABASE:
      res.send(results).end();
    });

    connection.release();
  });
});
```

when i test those requests obviously i can't make the post request, because basically the sql query and the body is different.

is there a way to make multiple POST request on the same TABLE?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `next()` middleware.

The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.

Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:

- Execute any code.
- Make changes to the request and the response objects.
- End the request-response cycle.
- Call the next middleware function in the stack.

So, in your code, change your first post request by including the `next` parameter and call it once the post is made like this,

```
app.post("/accesso", function(req, res, next) {
  connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    let sql = "DELETE FROM accesso where ?";
    let variabile = { idaccesso: req.body.idaccesso };
    connection.query(sql, variabile, function(error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results).end();
    });
    connection.release();
    next();
  });
});
```

Then place your second post request as is (without any change).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As your first request want to delete something from DB, you can define a `app.delete` method with the same path.

And let the second method be the same as `post`.

```
app.delete("/accesso", function(req, res) {
  connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    let sql = "DELETE FROM accesso where ?";
    let variabile = { idaccesso: req.body.idaccesso };
    connection.query(sql, variabile, function(error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results).end();
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```